# How to install mod_pagespeed module on apache that is running on Unix soalris

Tags: apache, unix, solaris

I want to configure **mod_pagespeed** module on **apache 2.x** running on **Unix solaris**.

Can u please tell me, Is **mod_pagespeed** module will work on above configuration.

If yes then please let me know from where i can download this module, and the steps to configure this module.

Your help will be appreciable.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [building tools](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/install-depot-tools) and the [native libraries](http://code.google.com/p/page-speed/wiki/HowToBuildNativeLibraries) required to compile [mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/mod) aren't available for Solaris. They need to be ported.

There has been no reported successful attempt to build mod_pagespeed on Solaris I'm aware of.

Comment: Thnx for reply, plz let me know is there any alternate way of mod_pageseed module. Actaully i want to combine all js file into one at apache level. There is another mod_concat module. Do u have any idea how to install it and steps to confiure it on apache 2.0.